# Do I have to really create multiple models?

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, dry

MS stack developer historically.

I have committed to retooling to the following stack

```
 angular -> ms web.api2 -> C# business objects -> sql server
```

Being old, I develop the database from requirements and use Codesmith to generate the business logic layer. (yes, I have heard of entity framework. even tried it once).

As I embrace Angular and web API 2

I find that Angular wants me to write a model on the front end. This seems to be just a data structure, I cant even add helper methods to it

So I also often write a class with helper methods that takes an instance of the model. Kind of ugly,but it does marry structure and logic.

I find that Web API2 wants me to write a model. This again seems to be just a data structure. I am exploring the dynamic data type, but really this doesn't buy me much. Instead of writing a class, I'm writing a mapping function.

The question is this:

Is there any way around having 3+ copies of each class spread across the stack? 
Codesmith is a very capable code generator... it can gen multiple files... but...

If its just a  couple data members, and 3 places, I can copy paste edit and get it done.

Just seems to me that now committing to keeping a data structure in synch in 3 different environments is setting oneself up for a lot of work.

I have spent the last 15 years trying to shove as much code as I can into a framework of inheritable classes so I can keep things DRY.

Am I missing something? Are there any patterns that can be suggested?

[I know this isn't a question tailored for SO, but it is where all the smart people shop. Downvote me if you feel honor bound to do so.]

Comment: I feel your pain. Our applications live in a database-oriented framework that predates EF by quite some time. We have code generators making the model objects for .NET+.NET Core on the server side and .NET+Angular on the client side. At least for the .NET things we can generate them as "partial class blahblah {...}" so that we can add methods and other logic in separate, non-generated files. In Angular we put the logic into Services wrapping the POCO collections.

Comment: Thanks for the response. woudl/does EF alleviate this, or just make it different?

Comment: EF only cares about EF. EF was (and still is as far as I know) a no-go for us because it requires a table/view for its Select operations, whereas the database framework we're dealing with gates everything through stored procedures to enforce row-level security. As a mental exercise I toyed with the idea of passing our user access tokens through `SET CONTEXT_INFO ...` and consuming `context_info()` inside views to maintain RLS but never got enough time to actually flesh it out - in EF you still have to modify all the SQL requests to inject this snippet of SQL before the EF-generated code.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely familiar with how CodeSmith generates it's classes, but if they are just plain-old-CLR-objects that serialize nicely, you can have WebApi return them directly to your Angular application. There are purists that will frown upon this, but depending on the application, there may be a justification.

Then, in the world of Angular, you have a few options, again, depending on your requirements/justification, and your application - again, purists will definitely frown upon some of the options.

1. create classes that match what's coming down from the server (more correct method)
2. Treat everything as "any", lose type safety, and just access properties as you need them i.e. don't create the model. (obviously less correct method)
3. find a code generation tool that will explore API end points to determine what they return, and generate your typescript classes for you.

Personally, using Entity Framework, I (manually) create my POCO's for database interraction, have a "view"/DTO class that WebAPI would then send back to the client, and a definition of the object in Typescript, but I am a control freak, and don't like generated code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  i've now heard POCO twice in 30 minutes. Twice more than ever before! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object.

Comment: so when you realize tShirts dont need a color, they need a bodyColor and sleeveColor, how many files do you have to update?

Comment: All other other design considerations aside, I'd have to update my SQL file/entity framework migration file, my POCO, my View/dto, my Angular class, my angular view(s), and any commands (i use a CQRS type pattern) that would interact with setting "tShirt colour".  Lots of changes is a downside - the upside is that (apart from the disconnect between TypeScript and C# classes), it's all type safe. Edit: by type safe, I mean, compile time safe - if I miss anything, it'll tell me at compile time

Comment: I find myself not only creating classes in TypeScript that match C#, but I intercept them on arrival at the client and convert them to an actual instance of the TypeScript class so that I have access to the methods as well as the properties. It is a pain, you'd think there would be a way to re-use C# classes in TypeScript, but once you decide how best to handle it, it becomes fairly straight-forward to follow the process each time. What also becomes apparent is that its far more likely for me to have methods on the TypeScript class than on the C# class which is usually just a DTO.

Comment: @AndrewP,  codeSmith can produce almost any text file you can imagine. I use it to create vb.net and c# classes from a table definition.  Ill experiment with what comes out in Angular if i pass one in. I expect the standard serialization will struggle w/ my classes.